# Function secret sharing and sharing a truth table

Tags: secret-sharing, terminology

I was reading a paper (*Function Secret Sharing* by Boyle, Gilboa and Ishai, [PDF](https://cs.idc.ac.il/~elette/FunctionSecretSharing.pdf)) on Function Secret Sharing and in that the author talked about a naive construction of a p party DPF wherein the truth table is additively shared.

What does it mean to share the truth table and how does it help?

Answer (score 2):

You can always naively create a FFS of some function $f$ using its truth table. Here is how you can do it:

- Write down the truth table of $f$, this table will have $2^N$ entries if the input of $f$ is $N$ bits
- Turn the truth table into a binary string $s$
- Secret share this string to $p$ parties, i.e., $s = s_1 \oplus \dots \oplus s_p$
- Send $s_i$ to party $i$
- When the party $i$ wants to evaluate $f(x)$, they just read the value at position $x$ of $s_i$